# How to return a Javascript object in Ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, json, https

How would the server side return a Javascript Object, not JSON, back to the client side in Ajax response?

For instance, can server side safely return the following in Ajax response?

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  collapsible: true,
  foo: function(){console.log("bar")}
});
```

I've tried JSON stringify. It returns the entire response in string. I think it's because stringify does not work on Javascript object.

The server has HTTPS using OpenSSL.

Doug

Comment: you need to `JSON.parse` there are many tutorials for this.

Comment: But how would it preserve and return 'function()' back to the client side?

Comment: you want to return plain JavaScript from an php script and call eval on response to execute it. Is that the safe/best way ? absolutely no. Try reading more on what Ajax requests send an what to do with response , you can call a function after you receive the response. Just read more about how Ajax works and how do applications use it to communicate in async way.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Thank you. How about return it in *.js file instead? The file extension would be .php because it is dynamically generated.